# How to Focus on nested Element by passing reference to the Parent Component in React?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a parent Component which sends a list of data to a List component which in turn sends it to a Label Component to display each data as a label.

I want to be able to focus on the label element when i click on it so that the appropriate style is applied ..

Below is the gist :-

```js
class ContainerComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        group: [1, 2, 3]
      };

      clickHandler = (name, ref) = > {
        // I am able to get the DIV as a html element here but calling .focus() on it dosent change the style where as when i explictly add focus using chrome debugger for the element it works.
        ref.focus() // not working
      }

      render() {
        return ( <
          ListComp group = {
            group
          }
          onClick = {
            clickHandler
          } >
        )
      }
    }

    function ListComp(props) {

      const data = props.group.map(... < label onClick = {} > )
      return ( <
        Label.. >
      )
    }


    function Label(props) {
      let ref = createref();
      // on focus style for the component is defined in this component 
      // i am making use of css modules 
      return ( <
        div ref = {
          ref
        }
        onClick = (name, ref) >

      )
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

How can we achieve such a functionality without having to pass a selected prop to the label component ? By default i would select the first element and keep the focus ..  or we can make it configurable.

Comment: Use a state variable for ListComp.

Comment: @10101010 i didnt get it can you be more elaborate , how does that help i already have the ref with me

Comment: So you want to use ref to change the color? `in this case i need to click it twice to change the focus or color` Isn't that obvious or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for this I would use Redux and fire off an action which therefore sets the property of the component that needs change, and make a listener that will listen for that specific prop and change style accordingly.

In this situation, id just pass down the event handler to the child component (remember to not call it when you pass it down, so do:

```
{() => {eventHandler()}}
```

and then in the child component do:

```
onClick={this.props.eventHandler(e)}
```

You will use the event to identify which element triggered it and then apply the class/style/prop to it.

Comment: This approach will not work out in this scenario without redux as even if we select how can we deselect and select the new element. We donot have the ref . That is the reason i am trying to find a way if possible with ref as then with prev ref we can unfocus it and then focus on the new ref..

Comment: Well this is why we use redux. Now you will have to set up an array in state which has the current status of each element (selected or not selected) and then toggle that state as well on click. So if you have initial position which is random/undeterminable then you will have to make API call twice. It slows down the application

Comment: I would never do this in my application, id take it apart before i do it but just set up state of child components, and pass a toggleEvent() function as prop to them and then when you call it, pass in the event as before, but also call setState on parent component and grab the component and use its position in the parent HTML element to find its nth position and use it as index to you array which contains the state of the child components.

Comment: I get that but but that the question was i donot want to use redux here as i feel i have the ref to the element and the focus should work .. i get the use of redux here but i feel as i have the element can't it be don without it and trying to connect my components

Comment: did you understand what i said?

Comment: Im at work now. I will check your problem in more detail at home. If you have GH repos, and feel like sharing code i can take a look at it in more detail later,

Comment: Yes i did understand what you are trying to say is have a state varaible called selected with each element and then use it toggle, but why should i if i have a ref that is the goal .` so in short the ref will not work is that what you are suggesting`

Comment: Ref is only used with arrays and objects, I don't even know if it is usable on simple variables. Try to do console.log(ref) see if you get undefined or the actual elemeng

Comment: i am able to see the full html ref . please check the question i have mentioned that but the focus on that element dosent work , i am able tp get the whole HTMLNODE

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with the Ref , I am not quite sure why but i changed it to use the `useRef()` hook.

**Label Component**

```
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className={[externalStyle, styles.container].join(' ')} onClick={() => onClickEvent(itemName, elementRef)} ref = {elementRef} tabIndex={1}> // added tabIndex and also changed to useRef
```

**Container Component**

```
   clickHandler = (name: string, ref) => {
    ref.current.focus(); // volla it worked 
  }
```

I tried using the `old form of Ref and also useRef()` without null previously `(el) => (const = el)`.

It works if some one has some explanation where i went wrong i will be happy to listen as i am able to wrap my head around. may be a nights sleep helped fix it :P